# Where is spark loading it's jars from?

Tags: spring, apache-spark

When specifying a jar at "spark.jars", and running on a standalone spark, without spark-submit. Where is the jar loaded from?

---

I have a Spring application that performs some spark operations on a Spark standalone running in Docker.

My application relies on various libraries such as MySQL JDBC, ElasticSearch, etc, and thus it fails running on the cluster which doesn't have them.

I assembled my jar with all its dependencies and moved it to the /jars directory in Docker. But still no luck.

```
13:28:42.577 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Fetching spark://192.168.99.1:58290/jars/xdf-1.0.jar with timestamp 1499088505128
13:28:42.614 [dispatcher-event-loop-0] INFO org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Executor is trying to kill task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7)
13:28:42.698 [Executor task launch worker-0] DEBUG org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient - Sending stream request for /jars/xdf-1.0.jar to /192.168.99.1:58290
13:28:42.741 [shuffle-client-7-1] DEBUG org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv - Error downloading stream /jars/xdf-1.0.jar.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/xdf-1.0.jar' was not found.
```

Now I noticed that it's looking for the jar on the driver host but I don't understand where it's trying to deploy it from. 
Any one has an 
idea where it's looking for that jar.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The jars are loaded from the driver node.
So, I didn't need to move my jar to the spark nodes. And I had to set the correct path to the dependency jar.

So this solved it:

```
spark.jars=./target/scala-2.1.1/xdf.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're essentially running a standalone application running in local mode, you will need to provide all jars on your own, as opposed to having spark-submit stage the spark run time for you. Assuming that you're using a build system such as maven or gradle, you will need to package all transitive dependencies with your application and remove any scope provided declarations.

The easiest in this case is to use assembly or maven-shade plugin to package a fat jar and then run that.

if you're running on cluster mode, you can programmatically submit your application using SparkLauncher, here's an example in scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher

object Launcher extends App {
  val spark = new SparkLauncher()
    .setSparkHome("/home/user/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
    .setAppResource("/home/user/example-assembly-1.0.jar")
    .setMainClass("MySparkApp")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .launch();
  spark.waitFor();
}
```

Keep in mind that in Yarn mode, you will also have to provide the path to your hadoop configuration.

Comment: I was looking to understand where to place my jar : on the driver node or the master/slave nodes. So this doesn't answer my question.